# Determine if the described set is a subspace. If so give a proof. If not explain why not. a and b are real numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the described set is a subspace. If so give a proof. If not explain why not. $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

The subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of the vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a\\ 0\\ b\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: @Casteels yes I need to show that S contains the 0 vector and is closed under scalar and addition. My problem is the answer the book gives me makes me more confused than anything. The answer is this, "This is a subspace, equal to $\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$". I dont know how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer will be clear to you when you look back at it a few months from now. For now, just use the definitions (more like theorems really) that

$W$ is a subspace if and only if $W$ satisfies the following three conditions:

1. The zero vector is in $W$. (Mouse over for more hints)

   > Let $a=b=0$, then the zero vector is in $W$.
2. If $u,v\in W$, then $u + v\in W$.

   > Use the fact that $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ then $a+b\in\mathbb{R}$.
3. If $u\in W$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then $cu\in W$

   > Use the fact that $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ then $ab\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks! but why would the answer be $\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ ?

Comment: The span of two vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ is the set of all vectors that can be written in the form $a\vec{v}+b\vec{w}$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$. Can you write a vector in your subspace in this form?

Comment: @Casteels i dont follow..

Comment: Is a vector of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a\\ 0\\ b\end{bmatrix}$ equal to $a\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes, i understand now, thanks! @Casteels